Export logs to S3 via AWS FireLens on AWS ECS without metadata and JSON format
Export logs to Amazon S3 using AWS FireLens on AWS ECS, ensuring that the logs are in plain text format without any JSON structure or additional metadata fields.
These are my settings.
1,task define.
{
    "family": "teitou-test",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "firelens-test",
            "image": "nexteng/firelens-test:latest",
            "cpu": 1024,
            "memory": 2048,
            "memoryReservation": 1024,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "firelens-test-8080-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 8080,
                    "hostPort": 8080,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "ulimits": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awsfirelens",
                "options": {
                    "bucket": "teitou-assets",
                    "total_file_size": "1M",
                    "s3_key_format": "/ecs-logs/app-logs/%Y/%m/%d/",
                    "use_put_object": "On",
                    "upload_timeout": "1m",
                    "region": "ap-northeast-1",
                    "Name": "s3"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "systemControls": []
        },
        {
            "name": "log_router",
            "image": "nexteng/aws-for-fluent-bit-delta:init-latest",
            "cpu": 1024,
            "memory": 2048,
            "memoryReservation": 1024,
            "portMappings": [],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "user": "0",
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awsfirelens",
                "options": {
                    "bucket": "teitou-assets",
                    "total_file_size": "1M",
                    "s3_key_format": "/ecs-logs/firelens-logs/%Y/%m/%d/",
                    "use_put_object": "On",
                    "upload_timeout": "1m",
                    "region": "ap-northeast-1",
                    "Name": "s3"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "systemControls": [],
            "firelensConfiguration": {
                "type": "fluentbit"
            }
        }
    ],
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/teitou-test-task-role",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "volumes": [],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "2048",
    "memory": "4096",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    }
}

2,fluent-bit.conf
[SERVICE]
    Flush         1
    Daemon        On
    Log_Level     info

[INPUT]
    Name          forward
    Listen        0.0.0.0
    Port          24224

[FILTER]
    Name          ecs
    Match         *
    enable-ecs-log-metadata false

[FILTER]
    Name          lua
    Match         *
    script        /fluent-bit/etc/transform_log_record.lua
    call          transform_log_record

[FILTER]
    Name          record_modifier
    Match         *
    Remove_key    container_id
    Remove_key    container_name
    Remove_key    source
    Remove_key    ecs_cluster
    Remove_key    ecs_task_arn
    Remove_key    ecs_task_definition

[FILTER]
    Name          modify
    Match         *
    Add           log_level INFO

[OUTPUT]
    Match           *
    compression     gzip
    format          out_logfmt
    log_key         log

3,transform_log_record.lua
function transform_log_record(tag, timestamp, record)
    local log_content = record["log"] or "No log content found"

    local formatted_timestamp = os.date("!%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", math.floor(timestamp / 1000)) .. string.format(".%03dZ", timestamp % 1000)

    local date_part, rest = log_content:match("^(%d%d%d%d%-%d%d%-%d%dT%d%d:%d%d:%d%d%.%d%d%d)%d*Z (.+)$")
    local formatted_log_content

    if date_part and rest then
        formatted_log_content = formatted_timestamp .. " " .. date_part .. "Z " .. rest
    else
        formatted_log_content = formatted_timestamp .. " " .. log_content
    end

    local new_record = {}
    new_record["log"] = formatted_log_content

    return 1, timestamp, new_record
end

4,Dockfile
FROM public.ecr.aws/aws-observability/aws-for-fluent-bit:init-latest

COPY fluent-bit.conf /fluent-bit/etc/fluent-bit.conf
COPY transform_log_record.lua /fluent-bit/etc/transform_log_record.lua

Then I received the following log.
{"date":"2024-11-01T11:53:44.708115Z","container_id":"24b806a55d8e4922b11df2033116005e-0468524152","container_name":"firelens-test","source":"stdout","log":"2024-11-01T11:53:44.707Z  WARN 1 --- [demo] [   scheduling-1] c.example.firelens_test.DemoApplication  : WARN log at: 2024-11-01 11:53:44","ecs_cluster":"teitou-test","ecs_task_arn":"arn:aws:ecs:ap-northeast-1:965128939651:task/teitou-test/24b806a55d8e4922b11df2033116005e","ecs_task_definition":"teitou-test:21"}

I would like it to look like the following, without JSON format and without metadata.
2024-11-01T11:53:44.708Z 2024-11-01T11:53:44.707Z  WARN 1 --- [demo] [   scheduling-1] c.example.firelens_test.DemoApplication  : WARN log at: 2024-11-01 11:53:44

Can someone tell me what I should do? Thanks.
